# How to create directories using samba client

Tags: java, filesystems, mkdir, samba, directory

I have a java code for samba client that puts a file from my unix machine to a windows machine. I need to check if a directory exits, and if not, create the directory and then put the file in that directory. I am able to put the file in an existing directory. It is the creating a new directory part that seems tricky.

Comment: which lib do you use?

Comment: JCIFS lib. to be specific, jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication, jcifs.smb.SmbException, jcifs.smb.SmbFile, jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you use JCIFS lib you can create a directory using `SmbFile`

```
 SmbFile sFile = new SmbFile(path, authentication);        
 sFile.mkdir();
```

For more information see [the documentation](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/jcifs/smb/SmbFile.html)

Comment: How do i check if the directory exits? How do i give a name to the directory?

Comment: @RKPoddar `sFile.exists();` with the path you specify the directory name. See the documentation from my answer